# MongoDB find() slow when querying a 64-bit integer field

Tags: mongodb, performance, find, int64

I have a Mongo collection called Elements containing ~9 million documents. Each document has the following structure:

```
{
  _id : "1",
  Timestamp : Numberlong(12345),
  Nationality : "ITA",
  Value: 5
}
```

If I run the following query:

```
db.Elements.find({ Nationality: 'ITA' })
```

the query performs fast (a few milliseconds).

If, instead, I run the following query:

```
db.Elements.find({ Timestamp: 12345 })
```

the query is slow, in the order of magnitude of tens of seconds. Obviously, if I add an index on `Timestamp`, the query runs much faster. Running the same query on the field `Value`, which is of type Int32, runs as fast as the first query.

What I am trying to understand is: why would the second query (without index) perform significantly worse than the first? Does Mongo treat Int64 values differently than other values?

Comment: Also please include `explain("executionStats ")` for both types of integers. with and without indexes

Comment: Thank you @JohnnyHK for the suggestion. I've just done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was making a mistake.

I was using Robomongo to execute the queries; by default, Robomongo pages the results (the default page size is 50 items).

Because the `Timestamp` field contains values that are almost always different, the query had to perform an almost-full scan before it could fill up and return one page. On the other hand, because the other fields contain values that have a limited range (the `Value` field, although it is Int32, has a limited domain in my application) I was getting results quickly because I was only looking at the first page.

When I run the same queries without pages (e.g. by appending a `count` or obtaining an execution plan) all the queries have poor performances without indexes.

Therefore, there doesn't seem to be any special treatment of Int64 values as opposed to other primitive types.